# An error when redirecting a list of objects to reduce function with lambda

Tags: python, object, lambda, reduce, functools

Here is the simple code.

```
class C:
  def __init__(self):
    self.l = [1,2,3]

a = C()
b = C()
c = C()

reduce(lambda x,y: x.l + y.l, [a,b,c])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'l'
```

I know there are several other ways. But I want to see why this doesn't work.

The output should be the same given by

```
sum([x.l for x in [a,b,c]], [])
```

which is

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: What is the expected result? `x.l + y.l` produces a list which will be fed back into the next call to reduce. Your function expects both arguments to be `C` objects. For that to hold true, you need to return a `C` object. [This](https://ideone.com/YqEiX1) code runs, but may not do what you need it to do.

Comment: What I expected is `sum([x.l for x in [a,b,c]], [])` So, did you mean this cannot write as one lins code?

Comment: yes it probably can but I just made it a function to allow me to put print statements in there. The difference between my code and the answer is that the result is a `C` object. Might be what you want, might not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function passed as the first argument to reduce takes 2 arguments, the first is the result of the previous reduction (or the first item in the iterable if no initial value is given). In your case, after the first 2 lists have been added together `x` is now a list when passed to the lambda for the second iteration and doesn't have an attribute `l` as it is not an instance of `C`

If you run your list through [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) you can extract the list from all the objects and pass them to the reduce

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda z: z.l, [a,b,c]))
```

Comment: Clear answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As Iain says in his answer, the problem hits after the first term is evaluated, since your types stop matching.

Reduce is of the form: `reduce(f(B,A)->B, [A], optional B) -> B`

You provide a function that has a signature of `f(C, C) -> [int]`

`reduce(lambda x,y: x.l + y.l, [a,b,c])`

which doesn't match `f(B,A)->B`.  You can clearly fix this in two ways, by changing the first argument (1) or the return (2)

(1) `f(int, C) -> int`. Where A is C and B is [int].

`reduce(lambda x, y: x + y.l, [a, b, c], [])`

(2) `f(C, C) --> C`.  Where A is C and B is also C.

```
def add_c(c1, c2):
    ret = C()
    ret.l = c1.l + c2.l
    return ret
reduce(add_c, [a, b, c]).l
```

Note the `.l` to extract your list

Note that the second is only ugly because your class is pretty silly, and has no init.  Also the lowercase L as a variable is unfortunate.